# Angular 8 : Binding elements to an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to achieve following

[image: elements_in_loop]

I have 2 fields description and Price.On click of plus button i get another input fields (Input 2 and Price 2) and so on. 
I want to bind these fields description and Price to an array of an object.

```
additionsOfProductArray: Array<NewProductAddition>=[];
class NewProductAddition{

  additionDescription:string;
  additionPrice:number;
}
```

what i am trying and is not working:

```
 <div class="row mt-5"
        *ngFor="let currentNumber of numberOfTimesAdditionArray | slice:0:numberOfTimesAdditions;let i = index">
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="additionDescription" placeholder="Auswahl Beschriebung Eingeben"
            [(ngModel)]="additionsOfProductArray[i].additionDescription">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
          <div class=" ml-5 input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control col-xs-3 priceinput" min="1" step="any"  name="articlePrice"
              [(ngModel)]="additionsOfProductArray[i].additionPrice">
            <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

Button Click

```
<div class="col-2">
          <button (click)="increaseTheAdditionNumber()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </button>
        </div>


  increaseTheAdditionNumber(){
    this.numberOfTimesAdditionArray=[];
    this.numberOfTimesAdditionArray= [...Array(++this.numberOfTimesAdditions).keys()] ;
  }


 numberOfTimesAdditionArray=[...Array(this.numberOfTimesAdditions).keys()];
  numberOfTimesAdditions=1;
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: lesnar, can you create a stackblitz for the issue to replicate..Its hard without producing one

Comment: You could use reactive forms with a form array.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen any other possibility apart from using reactive forms ?

Comment: @AluanHaddad oh its  [(ngModel)] , it was just desperate try to see if it works with one way binding.

Comment: Also, why not ngfor over  additionsOfProductArray? Your range variable isn't even being used

Comment: @AluanHaddad ngFor is only for creating the input elements in loop. slice:0:numberOfTimesAdditions;let i = index is only for how many elements i have in the end and user can totally control it using button click. If i can optimize it somehow,i would appreciate the help.

Comment: Show the code for button click

Comment: @AluanHaddad i have updated  the code for button click. please have a look.

Comment: you need to add a new item at the end of `additionsOfProductArray`

Comment: @AluanHaddad i am not sure if i understand it properly.I need to add for each element  pair (input field and price) in my array and yes at the end of additionsOfProdutArray. how should i do that ?

Comment: In your click Handler, you are increasing the number of items that are meant to be in the array and there by the index, but you aren't actually adding an item in there so there's nothing to bind because there's nothing at that index

Comment: @AluanHaddad right. but i would like to add the input at that index. i don't need 2 way binding,only  one way binding ?

Comment: actually, you do need two way binding.  but every time you increase the counter you need to push into the array

Comment: @AluanHaddad btw. i do not want to add the item on a click of an element , otherwise i will always have n-1 elements in my array since button will not be clicked after the last input.  I know i have empty array and i want to push the item in the array and i thought i can be  binded with the help of ngModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please can you try to use this example

**in template**

```
<div class="row mt-5"
        *ngFor="let product of additionsOfProductArray; let i = index">
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="additionDescription" placeholder="Auswahl Beschriebung Eingeben"
            [(ngModel)]="product.additionDescription">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
          <div class=" ml-5 input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control col-xs-3 priceinput" min="1" step="any"  name="articlePrice"
              [(ngModel)]="product.additionPrice">
            <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**in Ts**

```
increaseTheAdditionNumber(){
    this.additionsOfProductArray.unshift(new NewProductAddition());
    // or the example below if you want to 
    // this.additionsOfProductArray.push(new NewProductAddition());
}
```

I see in the comments you don't want to add items into your `additionsOfProductArray` array. Please can you explain why? maybe we can find another solution with adding the element into `additionsOfProductArray` array.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was suggesting.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry i did not get it properly. now i know what you meant.